# Objects of lower dimension don't intersect in higher dimensional space

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology

One of my professors mentioned in his lecture that generically, objects of lower dimension do not intersect in ambient space of sufficiently large dimension.

For instance, consider two balls (smooth manifolds) $M,N$ lying in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ with dimension $m,n$ repectively. If $p > m+n$ , then generically they do not intersect. Here 'generically do not intersect' means, as far as I am concerned, that if we consider

$$\Gamma := \{\phi | \phi :\mathbb{R}^{p} \to \mathbb{R}^{p} \ is \ a \ translation \ such \ that \ \phi (M) \cap N \neq \emptyset \}$$

Then $\cup _{\phi \in \Gamma} \phi (M)$  has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$.

The professor then commented that the above is a consequence of Sard's theorem, which states:

Let $f: U \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{p} $ be a smooth map. Then the set of critical values (image of critical points, i.e. image of points at which $df$ is not surjective) of $f$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$

I am not sure if I got the correct notion of 'generically do not intersect', and I failed to see the connection between this statement and Sard's thoerem. Any hint&comment&recommendation of reference is appreciated.

Comment: Can you prove that when $M$ and $N$ are linear subspaces?

Comment: Well, first, as warm-up, consider affine subspaces of dimensions $m,n$ such that $m+n$ is less than the dimension of the ambient linear space...

Comment: @paulgarrett  Well I think in this case, one can show that  $\cup _{\phi \in \Gamma} \phi (M)$ is again an affine space of dimension at most $m+n$, which has measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^p$  But in general, can we show that $\cup _{\phi \in \Gamma} \phi (M)$ is a manifold of dimension at most $m+n$ ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! <> The connection with Sard's theorem is, if $m + n < p$, then $df$ is not surjective since the domain has dimension at most $m + n$ and the codomain has dimension $p$.